# Use javascript validation to use jQuery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net

Hi I'm kind of new to Javascript and jQuery, what I want to do is a suggestion box that opens when the user clicks on a bottom div or button, and the div appears, so to do that I will use jQuery, the problem is that this will only be shown to logged users. I know how to validate a session state with Javascript, so here comes my question, how can I make this thing to only show to logged in users using only jQuery, or using a Javascript? Can I use both?

Note: I'm using .ASPX with C# on Visual Studio, this file uses a MasterPage

Here is the jQuery code, animations work kind of lame but it works as intended:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#chat_content").hide();
        $("#chat_content").css('bottom:-280px;');
        $("#chat_header").click(function () {
            $("#chat_content").toggle(250);
            $("#chat_content").animate({bottom:'0'});
        });
    });
</script>
```

Here the HTML, still no backcode on C#, that I will do later

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="chat_on" ID="cajadechat" runat="server">
    <div id="chat_header">
        <label id="bar_content_lbl">Chat en Línea</label>
        <img src="imagenes/botones/icono chat.png" id="chat_icon" />
    </div>
    <div id="chat_content">
        <span id="chat">
        En este momento no estamos conectados al Chat. Pero déjanos un mensaje y muy pronto nos contactaremos contigo. ¡Gracias!</span><br /><br />
        Su nombre*:<br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="txt_nombrechat" CssClass="chattext" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox><br />
        Su correo*:<br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="txt_correochat" CssClass="chattext" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox><br />
        Su pregunta*:<br />
        <asp:TextBox TextMode="MultiLine" CssClass="chatarea" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox><br />
        <asp:Button ID="btn_chat" CssClass="chatbutton" runat="server" Text="ENVIAR" />
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

And here the corresponding CSS

```
#contacto_ebook{
    position:fixed;
    right:150px;
    bottom:0;
    z-index:40;
    font-family: EuroStileTRegExt;
}
#chat_header{
    height:10px;
    width:260px;
    padding:10px 0 10px;
    background-color:#3a80cb;
    border-top-right-radius: 4px;
    border-top-left-radius: 4px;
}
#chat_header:hover{
    background-color:#499cf5;
    cursor:pointer;
}
#chat_content{
    height:280px;
    width:240px;
    background-color:#ffffff;
    text-align:left !important;
    padding:5px 10px 0 10px;
}
.chatbutton,.chattext,.chatarea{
    border-radius:3px;
    font-size:14px !important;
}
.chatbutton{
    height:40px;
    width:100%;
    margin-top:4px;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:#ffffff;
    box-shadow:none;
    background-color:#3a80cb;
    border:none; 
}
.chatbutton:hover{
    background-color:#499cf5;
}
.chattext,.chatarea{
    width:98%;
}
.chatarea{
    resize:none;
    outline-color:#3a80cb;
    height:52px;
}
#bar_content_lbl{
    color:#ffffff !important;
    font-size:14px !important;
    cursor:pointer;
    float:left;
    margin-left:10px;
}
#chat_icon{
    width:14px;
    height:14px;
    float:right;
    margin-right:10px;
}
#chat{
    text-align:justify !important;
    font-size:12px !important;
}
```

Comment: You should change `$("#chat_content").css('bottom:-280px;');` to be `$("#chat_content").css('bottom','-280px;');`.

Comment: Sort of hack, but you could have the server side code add a JS variable `var loggedIn = true` or `var loggedIn = false` and just check this value to see whether you should display the chat area or not.

Comment: @GaryStorey I will delete those lines on the jQuery since animation doesn't seem to be altered by it, thank you for pointing that :)

Comment: @GaryStorey so I should validate sessions with C# and then pass it to the jQuery? Can I do it with Javascript code or it messes up the jQuery?

Comment: jQuery is JavaScript so, no, they wont conflict.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you showing that the user is logged in? Is this an MVC application where you would be able to pass whether or not the user is logged in to the view? Then you would simply have to check a certain value on the DOM for whether or not the user is logged in and then display.

Modern browsers also have access to local storage, so you could store whether or not the user is logged in there, then check with javascript / jQuery and display accordingly.

Comment: No it is not an MVC application, so you suggest me to do it on server side with C# right? The thing is I only know how to pass it to ASP controls on HTML, and then get those values with a Javascript, I don't know if jQuery is capable of that, and if it is, how does it work.

Comment: Like GareyStory referenced above, JavaScript will not conflict with jQuery.

Comment: You will have to confirm that they are logged in server side and set it as a session. Then just check if they are logged in client side (since you have referred you already know how to do that in JS)